# AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1 - np.concatenate()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, axis

I want to concatenate two Numpy arrays using:

`np.concatenate((x,y.reshape(len(y),1)),axis=1)`

```
x
array([0.02542383, 0.05432444, 0.05592916, 0.0225309 , 0.05751058,
       0.05878261, 0.22347298, 0.32191235, 0.02411838, 0.25474137,
       0.04921983, 0.05736983, 0.05435839, 0.01524537, 0.05145499,
       0.07242904, 0.0506223 , 0.19234735, 0.05399891, 0.0410024 ,
       0.03938462, 0.07316477, 0.01000894, 0.01053533, 0.19936873,
       0.41291729, 0.04906247, 0.02723546, 0.01838214, 0.06434103,
       0.26908878, 0.10925268, 0.20858194, 0.03522793, 0.04499719,
       0.03410352, 0.02554791, 0.09302561, 0.03608627, 0.04368193,
       0.0271514 , 0.10271527, 0.07826084, 0.0166053 , 0.13437232,
       0.10548925, 0.07658451, 0.02076723, 0.03385754, 0.02455683,
       0.04214978, 0.1913195 , 0.02690974, 0.00714601, 0.14730562,
       0.09305552, 0.06944146, 0.11340955, 0.10525494, 0.04790132,
       0.05222447, 0.07743867, 0.04675769, 0.03493571, 0.0444973 ,
       0.09345969, 0.04027045, 0.03830293, 0.06390374, 0.06208764,
       0.04554125, 0.01742904, 0.03830261, 0.06413129, 0.02297048,
       0.03130876, 0.05521549, 0.14778974, 0.02137831, 0.17142863,
       0.03001146, 0.0176135 , 0.02883904, 0.03828   , 0.0202778 ,
       0.03461585, 0.12083221, 0.09090906, 0.04827766, 0.09999199,
       0.04247083, 0.13864809, 0.05922635, 0.0201329 , 0.04460693,
       0.04079322, 0.09750553, 0.0329554 , 0.05622296])

y
array([-0.02264446,  0.02542564,  0.04211922, -0.02332023,  0.00414108,
       -0.07603503,  0.21184521,  0.25857056, -0.02607102,  0.23368499,
       -0.06407522,  0.03897381,  0.03183766, -0.00508868, -0.0685759 ,
        0.02609174, -0.05864956,  0.15634075, -0.05422548, -0.03422613,
       -0.03380019,  0.04736571, -0.01302442,  0.00907436, -0.27951327,
        0.33882699, -0.06054897, -0.0261247 , -0.01752124, -0.08576588,
       -0.38324596,  0.08439715, -0.25341709, -0.02779527,  0.03147691,
        0.00644152, -0.02657317, -0.13311193, -0.02792882, -0.05643179,
       -0.0334482 , -0.09923616,  0.04261594, -0.01999107,  0.06820104,
       -0.13978655,  0.01447225, -0.02443087, -0.02772215, -0.01314321,
        0.01165549,  0.04264553, -0.02124456, -0.00884472, -0.0297479 ,
       -0.1328692 ,  0.05718329,  0.08992262,  0.01722447, -0.05886641,
        0.00873129,  0.05607011, -0.04796337, -0.01090274, -0.04853673,
       -0.13183856,  0.02047339, -0.04208248, -0.08593107,  0.01927994,
        0.02650769, -0.01800761, -0.04549789, -0.07029027, -0.00748984,
       -0.00123388,  0.00353033, -0.2068988 , -0.01468842,  0.17282685,
       -0.03570998, -0.01473052, -0.02985004,  0.03747841, -0.02289796,
       -0.04722409, -0.16702499, -0.12912483,  0.04226191, -0.14368337,
        0.01790933, -0.19011118,  0.03639563, -0.02296821, -0.04271722,
       -0.04067085, -0.142977  , -0.03574736, -0.00427567])
```

Both arrays have the same size:

```
x.shape
Out: (99,)

y.shape
Out: (99,)
```

However, when I run

```
AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

I've experimented with taking the transpose of both variables and with one of them, but no approach worked.

What input does `np.concatenate` accept? Based on [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) I would expect my approach to work.

Comment: Looks like `x` should be 2d, e.g. (99,n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @hpaulj said, it is expecting a 2d array - probably just weird way that library was written, adding the following code before you run clustering worked when I tried it:

```
x = x.reshape(99,1)
y = y.reshape(99,1)
```