# AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I already referred the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71551661/axiserror-axis-1-is-out-of-bounds-for-array-of-dimension-1-when-calculating-roc),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837068/axiserror-axis-1-is-out-of-bounds-for-array-of-dimension-1-np-concatenate) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771868/axiserror-axis-1-is-out-of-bounds-for-array-of-dimension-1-when-calculating-acc)

Am trying to run a `lassoCV` model and fit it on my training dataset.

So, I tried the below code (this works)

```
from numpy import arange
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold
# define model evaluation method
cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=5, random_state=1)
# define model
model = LassoCV(alphas=arange(0, 1, 0.01), cv=cv)
# fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
# summarize chosen configuration
print('alpha: %f' % model.alpha_)  # returns 0.78 as best value
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

However, when I try the below in next cell of jupyter notebook, I get an error

```
# define model
model_new = LassoCV(alphas=0.78)
# fit model
model_new.fit(X_train,pd.DataFrame(y_train))  # I also tried just X_train and y_train but still doesn't work

AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [136], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 model_new = LassoCV(alphas=0.78)
      3 # fit model
----> 4 model_new.fit(X_train,pd.DataFrame(y_train))

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_coordinate_descent.py:1687, in LinearModelCV.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)    1685             check_scalar_alpha(alpha, f"alphas[{index}]")    1686     # Making sure alphas is properly ordered.
-> 1687     alphas = np.tile(np.sort(alphas)[::-1], (n_l1_ratio, 1))    1689 # We want n_alphas to be the number of alphas used for each l1_ratio.    1690 n_alphas = len(alphas[0])

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in sort(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:998, in sort(a, axis, kind, order)
    996 else:
    997     a = asanyarray(a).copy(order="K")
--> 998 a.sort(axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
    999 return a

AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

My shape of X_train and y_train looks like below

[image]

**updated post**

[image]

Comment: pass the model X_train.values, not pandas dataFrame.

Comment: I already tried that. Same error

Comment: @MohammadAhmed - you can see updated screenshot above

Comment: show me `X_train.values.shape`

Comment: it is `(4299, 3)` . same as shown above for X_train

Comment: I have posted the answer, check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, give alpha in nump array

```
reg = LassoCV(alphas=np.array([0.5]), cv=5, random_state=0).fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: one quick question. I don't have to run my `model_new=LassoCV(alpha=0.78)` statement right? Because when I did `model = LassoCV(alphas=arange(0, 1, 0.01), cv=cv)
# fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)`, does this mean model already fit the model using 0.78 as alpha value? or I should fit again after getting 0.78

Comment: when you try to fit the model two times it fits it with new parameter, I hope you are trying to ask this.

Comment: In my code above, you see two model initialization and fit statements. Is it necessary to write the 2nd model initialization and fit statement (model_new I mean)? I want to fit odel based on the best value for alpha. So, should I initialize and fit the mode again - like I did using `model_new`

Comment: Yes, you need to fit it again on the new value of alpha.